# Error when Connecting Doosan robot arm

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a new Doosan A0509s arm. I am trying to run it using ROS.

The virtual mode works and launches properly when using the following -

> roslaunch dsr_launcher
> dsr_moveit.launch model:=a0509

The problem arises when I am connecting the Real robot. I am running the following -

> roslaunch dsr_control
> dsr_moveit.launch model:=a0509
> host:=192.168.137.100 mode:=real

But, I am getting the following errors -

> Connection refused  [ERROR]
> [1674121841.041127378]: [dsr_control]
> Error initializing robot

> [dsr01a0509-3] process has died [pid
> 40413, exit code 255, cmd
> /home/anirban/catkin_ws/devel/lib/dsr_control/dsr_control_node
> __name:=dsr01a0509 __log:=/home/anirban/.ros/log/bb3cbe20-97de-11ed-9a96-67be539470cf/dsr01a0509-3.log].
> log file:
> /home/anirban/.ros/log/bb3cbe20-97de-11ed-9a96-67be539470cf/dsr01a0509-3*.log

I am able to ping to 192.168.127.100 when using the real robot, but ROS is unable to connect to it.

System details -
Ubuntu 20.04
Ros Noetic

Can you please help me debug this issue?
Thank you.

---

Update : What I tried till now -

1. Ping - Pinging the ip 192.168.137.100 works. But error still exists.
2. Tried running with admin privilages  sudo i -

> $sudo -i

then cd into catkin workspace, then source. Then run the roslaunch. Did not work.

3. Checked firewall using ufw.

> $sudo ufw

status Shows inactive. My Laptop is connected directly to the Robot Controller via Ethernet cable.

---

Update : I am adding the images of the robot, system and errors.

1. Ros - [image: image description]--[image: image description]
2. Error - [image: image description]
3. Wired connection - [image: image description][image: image description]
4. Robot Teaching pendant - [image: image description]

---

Entire terminal when I run

> roslaunch dsr_control
> dsr_moveit.launch model:=a0509
> host:=192.168.137.100 mode:=real
> port:=12345

```
anirban@anirban-X556UQK:~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch dsr_control dsr_moveit.launch model:=a0509 host:=192.168.137.100 mode:=real port:=12345
... logging to /home/anirban/.ros/log/83c6d0ae-9e26-11ed-8965-8fa9bb3397d0/roslaunch-anirban-X556UQK-6161.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
started roslaunch server http://anirban-X556UQK:45415/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /dsr01a0509/command: True
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint1_position/joint: joint1
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint1_position/pid/d: 200.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint1_position/pid/i: 100.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint1_position/pid/i_clamp: 500
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint1_position/pid/p: 500.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint1_position/type: position_controll...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint2_position/joint: joint2
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint2_position/pid/d: 250.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint2_position/pid/i: 100.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint2_position/pid/i_clamp: 500
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint2_position/pid/p: 500.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint2_position/type: position_controll...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint3_position/joint: joint3
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint3_position/pid/d: 40.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint3_position/pid/i: 20.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint3_position/pid/i_clamp: 500
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint3_position/pid/p: 300.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint3_position/type: position_controll...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint4_position/joint: joint4
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint4_position/pid/d: 40.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint4_position/pid/i: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint4_position/pid/i_clamp: 500
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint4_position/pid/p: 100.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint4_position/type: position_controll...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint5_position/joint: joint5
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint5_position/pid/d: 25.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint5_position/pid/i: 20.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint5_position/pid/i_clamp: 500
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint5_position/pid/p: 200.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint5_position/type: position_controll...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint6_position/joint: joint6
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint6_position/pid/d: 25.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint6_position/pid/i: 20.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint6_position/pid/i_clamp: 500
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint6_position/pid/p: 300.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint6_position/type: position_controll...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint_position_controller/joints: ['joint1', 'joint...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint_position_controller/publish_rate: 20
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint_position_controller/type: position_controll...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint_publisher/publish_rate: 150
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint_publisher/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint_trajectory_controller/joints: ['joint1', 'joint...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint_trajectory_controller/publish_rate: 20
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_joint_trajectory_controller/type: position_controll...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/angular/z/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/angular/z/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/angular/z/max_acceleration: 6.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/angular/z/max_velocity: 2.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/base_frame_id: base_link
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/cmd_vel_timeout: 0.25
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/enable_odom_tf: False
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/estimate_velocity_from_position: False
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/left_wheel: ['front_left_whee...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/linear/x/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/linear/x/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/linear/x/max_acceleration: 3.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/linear/x/max_velocity: 1.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0....
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/right_wheel: ['front_right_whe...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0....
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/type: diff_drive_contro...
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
 * /dsr01a0509/dsr_velocity_controller/wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.875
 * /dsr01a0509/gripper: none
 * /dsr01a0509/host: 192.168.137.100
 * /dsr01a0509/mobile: none
 * /dsr01a0509/mode: real
 * /dsr01a0509/model: a0509
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/allow_trajectory_execution: True
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/arm/longest_valid_segment_fraction: 0.005
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/arm/planner_configs: ['SBL', 'EST', 'L...
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/arm/projection_evaluator: joints(joint1,joi...
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/capabilities: 
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/controller_list: [{'name': 'dsr_jo...
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/controller_manager_name: /
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/controller_manager_ns: /
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/disable_capabilities: 
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/jiggle_fraction: 0.05
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/max_range: 5.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/max_safe_path_cost: 1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/moveit_controller_manager: moveit_simple_con...
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/moveit_manage_controllers: True
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/octomap_resolution: 0.025
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/balanced: 0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/cache_cc: 1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/extended_fmt: 1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/heuristics: 1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/nearest_k: 1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/num_samples: 1000
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/optimality: 1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/radius_multiplier: 1.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BFMT/type: geometric::BFMT
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECE/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECE/failed_expansion_score_factor: 0.5
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECE/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECE/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BKPIECE/type: geometric::BKPIECE
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BiEST/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BiEST/type: geometric::BiEST
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/cost_threshold: 1e300
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/frountier_node_ratio: 0.1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/frountier_threshold: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/init_temperature: 100
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/temp_change_factor: 0.1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/BiTRRT/type: geometric::BiTRRT
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/EST/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/EST/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/EST/type: geometric::EST
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/FMT/cache_cc: 1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/FMT/extended_fmt: 1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/FMT/heuristics: 0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/FMT/nearest_k: 1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/FMT/num_samples: 1000
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/FMT/radius_multiplier: 1.1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/FMT/type: geometric::FMT
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/KPIECE/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/KPIECE/failed_expansion_score_factor: 0.5
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/KPIECE/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/KPIECE/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/KPIECE/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/KPIECE/type: geometric::KPIECE
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECE/border_fraction: 0.9
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECE/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.5
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECE/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/LBKPIECE/type: geometric::LBKPIECE
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRT/epsilon: 0.4
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRT/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRT/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/LBTRRT/type: geometric::LBTRRT
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/LazyPRM/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/LazyPRM/type: geometric::LazyPRM
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/LazyPRMstar/type: geometric::LazyPR...
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/PDST/type: geometric::PDST
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/PRM/max_nearest_neighbors: 10
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/PRM/type: geometric::PRM
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/PRMstar/type: geometric::PRMstar
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/ProjEST/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/ProjEST/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/ProjEST/type: geometric::ProjEST
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/RRT/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/RRT/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/RRT/type: geometric::RRT
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/RRTConnect/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/RRTConnect/type: geometric::RRTCon...
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/RRTstar/delay_collision_checking: 1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/RRTstar/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/RRTstar/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/RRTstar/type: geometric::RRTstar
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/SBL/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/SBL/type: geometric::SBL
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/SPARS/dense_delta_fraction: 0.001
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/SPARS/max_failures: 1000
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/SPARS/sparse_delta_fraction: 0.25
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/SPARS/stretch_factor: 3.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/SPARS/type: geometric::SPARS
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwo/dense_delta_fraction: 0.001
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwo/max_failures: 5000
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwo/sparse_delta_fraction: 0.25
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwo/stretch_factor: 3.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/SPARStwo/type: geometric::SPARStwo
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/degree: 16
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/estimated_dimension: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/max_degree: 18
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/max_pts_per_leaf: 6
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/min_degree: 12
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/min_valid_path_fraction: 0.2
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/type: geometric::STRIDE
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/STRIDE/use_projected_distance: 0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/frountierNodeRatio: 0.1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/frountier_threshold: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/goal_bias: 0.05
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/init_temperature: 10e-6
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/k_constant: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/max_states_failed: 10
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/min_temperature: 10e-10
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/range: 0.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/temp_change_factor: 2.0
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planner_configs/TRRT/type: geometric::TRRT
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planning_plugin: ompl_interface/OM...
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_geometry_updates: True
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_planning_scene: True
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_state_updates: True
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/planning_scene_monitor/publish_transforms_updates: True
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/request_adapters: default_planner_r...
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/start_state_max_bounds_error: 0.1
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_execution_duration_scaling: 1.2
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_goal_duration_margin: 0.5
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/trajectory_execution/allowed_start_tolerance: 0.01
 * /dsr01a0509/move_group/use_controller_manager: True
 * /dsr01a0509/name: dsr01
 * /dsr01a0509/port: 12345
 * /dsr01a0509/rate: 10
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_kinematics/arm/kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_pl...
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_kinematics/arm/kinematics_solver_attempts: 5
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_kinematics/arm/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_kinematics/arm/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.05
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint1/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint1/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint1/max_acceleration: 0
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint1/max_velocity: 2.094
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint2/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint2/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint2/max_acceleration: 0
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint2/max_velocity: 2.094
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint3/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint3/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint3/max_acceleration: 0
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint3/max_velocity: 3.142
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint4/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint4/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint4/max_acceleration: 0
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint4/max_velocity: 3.927
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint5/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint5/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint5/max_acceleration: 0
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint5/max_velocity: 3.927
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint6/has_acceleration_limits: False
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint6/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint6/max_acceleration: 0
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_planning/joint_limits/joint6/max_velocity: 3.927
 * /dsr01a0509/robot_description_semantic: <?xml version="1....
 * /dsr01a0509/rviz_anirban_X556UQK_6161_3195294438742091615/arm/kinematics_solver: kdl_kinematics_pl...
 * /dsr01a0509/rviz_anirban_X556UQK_6161_3195294438742091615/arm/kinematics_solver_attempts: 5
 * /dsr01a0509/rviz_anirban_X556UQK_6161_3195294438742091615/arm/kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
 * /dsr01a0509/rviz_anirban_X556UQK_6161_3195294438742091615/arm/kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.05
 * /dsr01a0509/standby: 5000
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.15

NODES
  /
    dsr01a0509 (dsr_control/dsr_control_node)
  /dsr01a0509/
    controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    move_group (moveit_ros_move_group/move_group)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    rviz_anirban_X556UQK_6161_3195294438742091615 (rviz/rviz)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [6171]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 83c6d0ae-9e26-11ed-8965-8fa9bb3397d0
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6181]
started core service [/rosout]
process[dsr01a0509/controller_spawner-2]: started with pid [6188]
process[dsr01a0509-3]: started with pid [6189]
process[dsr01a0509/robot_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [6190]
process[dsr01a0509/move_group-5]: started with pid [6191]
[ INFO] [1674812378.633075970]: rate is 10

[ INFO] [1674812378.640493720]: name_space is dsr01, a0509

[ INFO] [1674812378.640541798]: [dsr_hw_interface] constructed
process[dsr01a0509/rviz_anirban_X556UQK_6161_3195294438742091615-6]: started with pid [6197]
[ WARN] [1674812378.707470299]: Falling back to using the move_group node's namespace (deprecated Melodic behavior).
[ INFO] [1674812378.719049842]: Loading robot model 'a0509'...
[ INFO] [1674812378.719103631]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[ WARN] [1674812378.719174720]: Link base_0 has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[ WARN] [1674812378.719265361]: Link link3 has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[ WARN] [1674812378.719295289]: Link link6 has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[ WARN] [1674812378.742293413]: Kinematics solver doesn't support #attempts anymore, but only a timeout.
Please remove the parameter '/dsr01a0509/robot_description_kinematics/arm/kinematics_solver_attempts' from your configuration.
[ INFO] [1674812378.805409208]: [dsr_hw_interface] init() ==> setup callback fucntion
[ INFO] [1674812378.805450706]: INIT@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
[ INFO] [1674812378.805469254]: [dsr_hw_interface] init() ==> arm is standby
[ INFO] [1674812378.825407692]: Publishing maintained planning scene on 'monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1674812378.828823888]: host 192.168.137.100, port=12345 bCommand: 1, mode: real

Connection refused
[ERROR] [1674812378.829097250]: [dsr_control] Error initializing robot
[ INFO] [1674812378.829458459]: Listening to 'joint_states' for joint states
[ INFO] [1674812378.840566307]: Listening to '/dsr01a0509/attached_collision_object' for attached collision objects
[ INFO] [1674812378.840657679]: Starting planning scene monitor
[ INFO] [1674812378.843513825]: Listening to '/dsr01a0509/planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1674812378.843581176]: Starting world geometry update monitor for collision objects, attached objects, octomap updates.
[ INFO] [1674812378.845703507]: Listening to '/dsr01a0509/collision_object'
[ INFO] [1674812378.847755078]: Listening to '/dsr01a0509/planning_scene_world' for planning scene world geometry
[ INFO] [1674812378.848611374]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
[ INFO] [1674812378.849754565]: Loading planning pipeline ''
[dsr01a0509-3] process has died [pid 6189, exit code 255, cmd /home/anirban/catkin_ws/devel/lib/dsr_control/dsr_control_node __name:=dsr01a0509 __log:=/home/anirban/.ros/log/83c6d0ae-9e26-11ed-8965-8fa9bb3397d0/dsr01a0509-3.log].
log file: /home/anirban/.ros/log/83c6d0ae-9e26-11ed-8965-8fa9bb3397d0/dsr01a0509-3*.log
[ INFO] [1674812378.907974174]: rviz version 1.14.19
[ INFO] [1674812378.908026003]: compiled against Qt version 5.12.8
[ INFO] [1674812378.908055888]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
[ INFO] [1674812378.911719435]: Using planning interface 'OMPL'
[ INFO] [1674812378.916463332]: Param 'default_workspace_bounds' was not set. Using default value: 10
[ INFO] [1674812378.917006591]: Param 'start_state_max_bounds_error' was set to 0.1
[ INFO] [1674812378.917779770]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1674812378.918430042]: Param 'start_state_max_dt' was not set. Using default value: 0.5
[ INFO] [1674812378.919572173]: Param 'jiggle_fraction' was set to 0.05
[ INFO] [1674812378.920528155]: Param 'max_sampling_attempts' was not set. Using default value: 100
[ INFO] [1674812378.920646468]: Using planning request adapter 'Add Time Parameterization'
[ INFO] [1674812378.920694836]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Workspace Bounds'
[ INFO] [1674812378.920732625]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Bounds'
[ INFO] [1674812378.920774423]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State In Collision'
[ INFO] [1674812378.920820114]: Using planning request adapter 'Fix Start State Path Constraints'
[ INFO] [1674812378.922042981]: Forcing OpenGl version 0.
[INFO] [1674812379.068318]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[ INFO] [1674812379.359125451]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1674812379.359261255]: OpenGL device: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
[ INFO] [1674812379.359367437]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6) limited to GLSL 1.4 on Mesa system.
[ INFO] [1674812382.690787682]: Loading robot model 'a0509'...
[ INFO] [1674812382.690941669]: No root/virtual joint specified in SRDF. Assuming fixed joint
[ WARN] [1674812382.691338338]: Link base_0 has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[ WARN] [1674812382.691590195]: Link link3 has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[ WARN] [1674812382.691863317]: Link link6 has visual geometry but no collision geometry. Collision geometry will be left empty. Fix your URDF file by explicitly specifying collision geometry.
[ WARN] [1674812382.710910562]: Kinematics solver doesn't support #attempts anymore, but only a timeout.
Please remove the parameter '/dsr01a0509/rviz_anirban_X556UQK_6161_3195294438742091615/arm/kinematics_solver_attempts' from your configuration.
[ INFO] [1674812382.782024968]: Starting planning scene monitor
[ INFO] [1674812382.784485349]: Listening to '/dsr01a0509/move_group/monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1674812382.997369147]: waitForService: Service [/dsr01a0509/get_planning_scene] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ WARN] [1674812383.941784903]: Waiting for dsr_joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ INFO] [1674812388.011057199]: Failed to call service get_planning_scene, have you launched move_group or called psm.providePlanningSceneService()?
[ INFO] [1674812388.011613888]: Constructing new MoveGroup connection for group 'arm' in namespace ''
[ WARN] [1674812389.942170994]: Waiting for dsr_joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ERROR] [1674812395.942670551]: Action client not connected: dsr_joint_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
[ INFO] [1674812395.960345668]: Returned 0 controllers in list
[ INFO] [1674812395.977766825]: Trajectory execution is managing controllers
[ INFO] [1674812395.977804800]: MoveGroup debug mode is ON
Loading 'move_group/ApplyPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/ClearOctomapService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupCartesianPathService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupExecuteTrajectoryAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupGetPlanningSceneService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupKinematicsService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupMoveAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPickPlaceAction'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupPlanService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupQueryPlannersService'...
Loading 'move_group/MoveGroupStateValidationService'...
[ INFO] [1674812396.037792111]: 

********************************************************
* MoveGroup using: 
*     - ApplyPlanningSceneService
*     - ClearOctomapService
*     - CartesianPathService
*     - ExecuteTrajectoryAction
*     - GetPlanningSceneService
*     - KinematicsService
*     - MoveAction
*     - PickPlaceAction
*     - MotionPlanService
*     - QueryPlannersService
*     - StateValidationService
********************************************************

[ INFO] [1674812396.038301816]: MoveGroup context using planning plugin ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
[ INFO] [1674812396.038343971]: MoveGroup context initialization complete

You can start planning now!

[ INFO] [1674812397.207668856]: Ready to take commands for planning group arm.
[WARN] [1674812409.075185]: Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
[dsr01a0509/controller_spawner-2] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/anirban/.ros/log/83c6d0ae-9e26-11ed-8965-8fa9bb3397d0/dsr01a0509-controller_spawner-2*.log
^C[dsr01a0509/rviz_anirban_X556UQK_6161_3195294438742091615-6] killing on exit
[dsr01a0509/move_group-5] killing on exit
[dsr01a0509/robot_state_publisher-4] killing on exit
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411605/error-when-connecting-doosan-robot-arm/) by [Anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/134859/anirban/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2023-01-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @Anirban,

By looking at your issue, I can conclude that you have the same IP address in your ubuntu and Teaching pendant.  Try to change the IP address to **192.168.137.101 or any other number (Not 100).**

You cannot have the same ip address on a network. (An IP address conflict happens when two or more devices in a network have the same IP address. This results to one or both of the devices not being able to communicate with each other.)

Then try and check what errors are you getting.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2023-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/134859/anirban/) on 2023-01-30**:
No unfortunately it did not work. Anyways, thanks a lot for the help!

**Comment by [Anirban](https://answers.ros.org/users/134859/anirban/) on 2023-01-30**:
But it did help..Yes I was setting it wrong it seems. I later changed the IP.